# Jasmine unit-testing: module is not defined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to run Jasmine unit-testing for my Angular application, but for some reason it tells me module is not defined. I've already searched for the solution and many solutions say **angular-mocks.js** was not referenced. 
I have added angular-mocks.js and it still tells me it's not defined.

My SpecRunner:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">    
<title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.0.3</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.3/jasmine_favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.3/jasmine.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.3/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.3/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.3/boot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.3/mokeAjax.js"></script>

<!-- include source files here... -->
<script src="../../public/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-mocks.js"></script>

<script src="../../public/javascripts/app.js"></script>

<script src="../../public/javascripts/controllers/calendarController.js"></script>
<script src="../public/javascripts/services/afsprakenService.js"></script>

<!-- include spec files here... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./spec/StockSpec.js"></script>

</head>

<body id="pagina">
</body>
</html>
```

And my StockSpec.js:

```
describe('myApp', function () {
beforeEach(function () {
    module('myApp');
})

it ('test', function () {
    expect(myApp).toBeDefined()

})

})
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm pretty certain my paths are correct;

[image]

EDIT: It's solved. My URL retrieving angular-mocks didn't contain the version number (facepalm).

Comment: Can we see your app.js file? Or just a relevant portion of it

Comment: @jagrut https://i.imgur.com/17A3OeY.png. That is everything in my app.js.

Comment: I usually write `beforeEach(module('myApp'));`, but not sure if that helps in this case

Comment: also make sure your paths are correct, it looks like you have different paths for files that seem to be in the same folder. I mean you initial `../..` seems to be different

Comment: @Gustav I did see the path of `afsprakenService.js` to be wrong, but that shouldn't be the issue. I'm simply checking if my `app.js` is defined.

Comment: Could you post the exact error? Is it that the module "myApp" is not defined or is it that the function `module` that is not defined?

Comment: Oh, you don't need (shouln't have?) `new`, when creating the module, just simply `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);` is fine. Also don't name the module and controller the same.

Comment: @Gustav the error: https://i.imgur.com/8njvrHs.png

Comment: Don't know what else might be wrong... Make sure you actually get angular-mocks from the cdn, or download it locally and you be sure. Double check the paths... Fix the other this with the code I mentioned (probably won't fix your current issue, but is still a good idea imo). Other than that I don't know..

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-mocks.js I'm not sure the google cdn still has angular-mocks, try this one

Comment: @Gustav I see the problem.. you have to add a version number in the URL when retrieving angular-mocks and in my URL, it says X.Y.Z. lol. It works now!

Comment: hehe so obvious really! Glad it worked!